# Uploading .rfa file

Tags: ee2, file-uploads

I'm trying to upload a .rfa to the file manager in EE2 but it's giving me the error "File not allowed.". I've added the mime type to config/mimes.php which is just application/octet-stream (I checked used chrome dev tools).

The allowed file type is "All" on both the File Upload Preferences and field type, it's under the servers file size limit and other file types such as .jpg and .zip work fine. I also disabled XSS security check. I've tried it on a different server and it's giving me the same problem. Anything else I can investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. In the end I had to load the site up locally and step through the php files using a debugger to find out what it was.

Although the file was being uploaded as `application/octet-stream` it was coming through as `application/CDFV2-corrupt` in ExpressionEngine. So I added `application/CDFV2-corrupt` to the list of mime types and it works.